# Rails complex form with variable number of admin pre-determined attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having troubles getting a solution for this Ruby on Rails problem (I'm quite new to this).

Scenario (Ruby on Rails 4 with Devise and other gems):

I have list of Exposers that belongs to a single User.

Each Exposer has some attributes (name, description, ecc) with fixed columns in the db.

The site admin can add some attributes (exposer_special_field) for all the Exposers of a single User which will be visible in the Exposer's form (update and create). These fields, right now, only contain a name property (translatable), but I'm planning to add some more informations such as data-type (integer or string) or similar.

Each Exposer will have a value (exposer_special_value) for each dynamic attribute.

Each User has a list of exposers with different custom fields, that's why I need this to be dynamic (otherwise I would try to add a dynamic column to the db when the admin adds a new attribute for ALL exposers).

These are my (simplified) models

exposer.rb

```
class Exposer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :exposer_special_values
  has_many :exposer_special_fields, through: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exposer_special_values,
                                :allow_destroy => true
```

exposer_special_field.rb

```
class ExposerSpecialField < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :fair
   has_many :exposer_special_values
   #the property is: name:string

end
```

exposer_special_value.rb

```
class ExposerSpecialValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exposer_special_field
  belongs_to :exposer
  #the property is : value:string
end
```

I honestly don't know how to make things work in exposers/_form.html.erb
I've tried (inside a form_for) this

```
 <% f.fields_for :exposer_special_values, @exposer.exposer_special_values do |ff| %>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= ff.label ff.object.exposer_special_field.name, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= ff.text_field :value, :class => 'text_field' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

My goal, as you can see, is to have a label with the special_field name in it and a corresponding value to be set on create/update.

Can anyone help me or redirect me to something useful?